# How to fire deviceready event in Chrome browser (trying to debug phonegap project)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap application and I'd like to be able to debug it in Chrome rather than on the phone.  However, I do the initialization of my code in an onDeviceReady() function that is triggered when PhoneGap fires the "deviceready" event.  Since Chrome doesn't fire this event, my code isn't ever initialized.

Here's a stripped down version of my code:

```
var dashboard = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", dashboard.onDeviceReady, false);
}); 

dashboard.onDeviceReady = function() {
    alert("hello!"); //this is never fired in Chrome
};
```

I've tried using the [StopGap](https://github.com/alunny/stopgap) code, which basically just does the following:

```
var e = document.createEvent('Events'); 
e.initEvent("deviceready");
document.dispatchEvent(e);
```

But when I run that code in the Chrome javascript console, the "hello" alert still doesn't trigger.  What am I doing wrong?  Or does chrome just not support firing "custom" events like deviceready?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Add this code to your onLoad handler function:

```
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    } else {
        onDeviceReady();
    }
```

Event "deviceready" is fired in cordova.js so I don't know a way to detect existence of this event in application code.

Comment: this definitely works. Know that it will preclude you from using your device browser to test your app as a web-based app (i.e. safari on iPhone etc). I will put my function as an answer just in case this matters to anyone else.

Comment: Just a side note: you probably want to wrap all of this inside a $(document).ready(function(){}); or equivalent for it to load correctly in the browser

Comment: It doesn't help you when you use development tools in chrome..

Answer (score 14):

Ended up pulling out the StopGap code and having to introduce a tiny delay (have this code running in a separate script than page-specific code):

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var e = document.createEvent('Events'); 
    e.initEvent("deviceready", true, false); 
    document.dispatchEvent(e);
}, 50);
```

Comment: Late update : e.initEvent requires more parameters these days , e.initEvent('deviceready',true,false)

Answer (score 9):

For my mobile site and mobile App I'm using the following code with jQuery:

```
function init() { ... };
if ("cordova" in window) {
    $(document).on("deviceready", init);
} else {
    $(init);
}
```

Comment: i believe aka user318696 for reference from other answers.

Answer (score 8):

Use the Ripple Mobile Emulator. It is free on the Chrome Web Store. When it is installed, navigate to the page you want to test it on, right click the page and choose Ripple Mobile Emulator > Enable. When prompted, choose PhoneGap.

The emulator is good, but it is still in beta so not everything has been implemented yet.

Ad@m

Comment: I've looked at Ripple... but the problem is that they don't support using file:///path/to/html to access local files on Chrome.  I'd also like to be able to demo the app on the web without having to do a lot of code rewrites, so figuring out some way to fire the deviceready event seems like the best way to go...

Comment: To fix that go to `about:flags` and enable access to file:// urls, then restart Chrome. If you can't see that in the list, make a copy of your Chrome shortcut on your desktop and add `--allow-access-file-urls` to the target text box. Ad@m

Comment: Or, you can try adding this before your event listener for deviceready: `var loadEvent="ondeviceready" in document?"deviceready":"load";` Then replace `"deviceready"` on your `document.addEventListener` line with `loadEvent`. Ad@m

Comment: Still working on this, but as a side note, the proper flag is: --allow-file-access-from-files (not --allow-access-file-urls)

Comment: Not really sure what I was doing before... I pulled out all the StopGap stuff and now I have:

    if (phSettings.FIRE_DEVICEREADY) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            var e = document.createEvent('Events');
            e.initEvent("deviceready");
            document.dispatchEvent(e);
        }, 50);
    }

And that works perfectly in Chrome (although the timeout seems a little kludgy).  Also, good advice on Ripple.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I was trying to remember the flag from the top of my head. Ad@m

Comment: Be careful. The ripple emulator as it stands (emulate.phonegap.com) doesn't support versions of PhoneGap after about 2.6. There's a new Apache-run ripple project to replace it, but it doesn't work the same way.

Answer (score 7):

I use Safari for debugging and do this:

```
//my standard PG device ready
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
//debug("onDeviceReady")
getDefaultPageSetup();

}

//then add this (for safari
window.onload = function () {
if(! window.device)
    onDeviceReady()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

user318696 had the magic I was looking for. "device" is defined in cordova and does not get defined when in a browser (non-phoneGap app wrapper).

EDITED:

I ran into a scenario where Cordova took quite a while to initialize on a device and the "original" answer here was no longer valid. I have moved on to requiring a parameter on the URL when running tests in the browser. (in the example I'm looking for "testing=" in the url of the original page)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // ALWAYS LISTEN
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", main, false);

    // WEB BROWSER
    var url = window.location.href;
    if ( url.indexOf("testing=") > -1 ) {
        setTimeout(main, 500);
    }

});
```

ORIGINAL:

I haven't dug deeply enough to know how long to trust this [could they start defining "device" in the browser in a future release?] But at least up to 2.6.0 this is safe:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // call main from Cordova
    if ( window.device ) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", main, false);
    }

    // from browser
    else {
        main();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

user318696's window.device detection works well. If using Kendo UI Mobile and PhoneGap, the following script will enable functionality in both PhoneGap builds and web browsers. This is based on Burke Holland's [PhoneGap Build Bootstrap Project for Kendo UI Mobile](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/getting-started-kendo-ui-mobile-phonegap-build.html) and is intended to be placed at the bottom of the page before the closing body tag.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var tkj = tkj || {};

    tkj.run = (function () {
        // create the Kendo UI Mobile application
        tkj.app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
    });

    // this is called when the intial view shows. it prevents the flash of unstyled content (FOUC)
    tkj.show = (function () {
        $(document.body).show();
    });

    (function () {
        if (!window.device) {
            //initialize immediately for web browsers
            tkj.run();
        }
        else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Browzr') > -1) {
            // blackberry
            setTimeout(tkj.run, 250)
        } else {
            // attach to deviceready event, which is fired when phonegap is all good to go.
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', tkj.run, false);
        }
    })();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Enhancing Chemik suggestion. The following code uses navigator.userAgent string to generically determine if the client browser is on a mobile platform.

The purpose of the separation from desktop browsers is to allow code verifying prior to compiling/installing android apk, etc. It is much faster to make a quick code change, refresh desktop browser vs. compiling in eclipse and loading on android. Another added bonus is the ability to use weinre in one tab & the index.html from android assets in another tab (and use firebug).

PS: weinre code is excluded since it has my private VPS info & UUID.

thx!

```
<!-- Framework:jQuery -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.2, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, user-scalable=yes" >
<link  href="./framework/jquery/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" title="JQuery Mobile">
<script src="./framework/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="./framework/jquery/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- Framework:Weinre -->

<!-- Framework:PhoneGap -->
<script src="./framework/phonegap/cordova-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var mobile = false;
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){mobile = true; onDeviceReady();}, false);
    } else {
        $(document).ready(onDeviceReady);   
    }
    function onDeviceReady() {
        setEvents();
        test();
        if (mobile) {
            navigator.notification.alert("Debugging-ready for\n" + navigator.userAgent);
        } else {
            alert("Debugging-ready for\n" + navigator.userAgent);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Please try to explain your answer in text, not only code. Make it easy to understand what the difference is between your answer and the others, what is it you have enhanced etc.

Answer (score 1):

You simulate events like this:

```js
const simulateEvent = (eventName, attrs = {customData:"data"}, time = 1000, target = document) => {
    let event = new CustomEvent(eventName, { detail:  attrs });    
    setTimeout(() => {
        target.dispatchEvent(event);
    }, time);
};

var divReady = document.querySelector('div#ready');

document.addEventListener('deviceready', (e) => {
 console.log("triggered with:", e.detail);
 divReady.innerHTML = `Ready! ${JSON.stringify(e.detail)}`;
});

simulateEvent('deviceready', {customData:"My custom data goes in event.detail"});
```

```html
<div id="ready"> Wait for ready... </div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer... too bad it's 5 years late but thanks for posting it! I learned something.