# Getting started with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I don't understand why I'm not getting an alert.  There are no errors in the console, and I'm sure it is finding the PhoneGap.js file.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/Matrix/PhoneGap/Inc/js/PhoneGap.js"></script>
<script>
function myDeviceReady() {
    alert('Ready!');
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", myDeviceReady, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: This is not working on my iPhone using either Safari or Google Chrome.

Comment: Environment? Targeted platform? (Which could be two different things altogether, of course...) You realize that you can't rely on pulling external JS libs (in particular, jQuery) like that in the full-blown app, right? All app files need to be local-hosted within the app structure, as far as I know.

Comment: Oh!  I'm browsing to it in my browser, not using an emulator.

Comment: I need to use my iPhone, don't I. D'uh!

Comment: That's not bad for testing general functionality, but you should be locally sourcing your support files. Yes, "deviceready" isn't an event supported by your desktop browser. :)

Comment: It's not working on my Safari browser on my iPhone either though.

Comment: "deviceready" is built into the Cordova library (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687099/how-to-fire-deviceready-event-in-chrome-browser-trying-to-debug-phonegap-projec) not into Safari. Also, how are you running it on your Safari browser on your iPhone? You should be running it via XCode (either in the emulator, or onto your device, assuming you have a developer license already, and your phone is properly set up), if you want to test this.

Comment: Thanks Mori57!  Now, as you can see, I am starting at square 1 when it comes to PhoneGap. I would like to see it working for the first time on my phone.   Wait: what's this about XCode?  My customer isn't going to need XCode in order to run my PhoneGap application, is he?  I'm just trying to get a proof-of-concept going here.

Comment: No, you have to use XCode to deploy it to an iPhone, or Eclipse to deploy it to an Android phone. If you're trying to show a proof of concept in the browser, the Cordova bits aren't going to do you any good, anyhow, as Cordova is just an abstraction library that lets you write to the Cordova API, which then talks to the device-specific APIs. If you want to show it off in a browser, you could try loading your html mockup in http://www.responsinator.com/ to give a VERY rough idea of what your app might look like when it's finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it to run in a Ripple emulator (see [this link](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/2/6/Using-Ripple-for-PhoneGap-Development)) but make sure use cordova.js not phonegap.js.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
window.addEventListener( 'load', myDeviceReady );
```

Checking `deviceready` has many issues. I find it easier to poll for `window.device` (which only exists if Phonegap is initialized).

Comment: Thanks ThinkingStiff, but I really want to learn how to use PhoneGap and not circumnavigate around it, or even emulate it.  I need to show that it will work as a proof-of-concept from beginning all the way to the device.  I'm not at the point where I've even STARTED developing on it yet.  I want to write a Hello World and pull it up on my iPhone (and have it tell me something about my device, like the accelerometer properties).

Comment: @Phillip I have several released apps written with PhoneGap. From my experience, I would recommend avoiding the `deviceready` event. Phonegap works just fine without using that event.