# Cordova deviceready is not working from webpage

Tags: cordova

I'm developing hybrid iOS app. I want to show one of the page from my website in the App. I am using cordova and it is loading expected page successfully but it is NOT firing "deviceready" event from the same page. I have already added eventlistener for "deviceready" still it is not firing deviceready
can any one tell me, how it would be work??

Comment: Issue try adding a delay for showing your page.... May be device ready is taking time to get called and secondly you can also check whether u have added cordova refernce

Comment: See this answer for a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10237209/417006

Comment: When do you navigate to the page on your website? at the start of the application or at a later time?

Comment: just thinking of moving it to website.